# Esspresso assertThat requires addtional Matcher when verifying navigation

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I am following [Google's example](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-testing#test_fragment_navigation) to test my fragment with a mock navControllor. I'm doing everything the same and I am getting this error from Espresso when using assertThat.[Error message I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Gp94.png)

It appears that i need to pass in an additional matcher which is not in the example Google provide. I don't know why this matcher is needed.

My dependency versions:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `assertThat` from the documentation comes from [Truth](https://truth.dev/), which you'd add to your project via that Gradle dependency:

```
androidTestImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:1.0.1"
```

Comment: Thanks Ian, please suggest to add that into the doc so it makes our life easier. Because the tutorial uses Espresso so I assumed it's from Espresso lool.

Comment: You can file issues against the documentation on [the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192697), which get triaged to the right team.